# C# compare random number to int

Tags: c#, random, compare

How do I compare a random generated number to an int?

```
Random i = new Random();

    static int generaCasuale(Random i)
    {
        return i.Next(7);
    }


generaCasuale(i);            
 if(i.Equals(0))
    MessageBox.Show(vincitore + " vince!", "GG EASY");
 else if (i.Equals(1)){           {
             MessageBox.Show(vincitore + " hai barato..", "GG EASY");
            } 
else if(i.Equals(2))
{
MessageBox.Show(perdente + " sei Rincoglionito?", "GG EASY");
}
```

.Equals doesn't work, while "==" gives me a compilation error

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(j) == 0) //doesn't work too
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` will always be of the type `System.Random` and will never be a number. Did you intend to compare the *value* of an `i.Next` call?

In your code, `generaCasuale` returns an int, but you're never using that return value; you're calling the method without assigning to anything. If you were to write `int x = generaCasuale(i);` then you could compare `x` with integers.

Comment: Very clear, I'm quite new to C# and programming languages in general.
I'm working on a big tic tac toe project, so I've added the phrases to say at the end of the game. Now I want them to be randomized and it works. Thank you =) oh anyway I love black metal too, Hail scandinavia

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the RNG not the result

you need to assign the result of `generaCasuale` to a variable and then use that to compare

```
int myNum = generaCasuale(i);

if (myNum == 1) //etc
```

By using `.Equals` you are doing a reference comparison between the RNG object and your int